# Can I justify text in Vim?

Tags: wrapping, word-processing, alignment

The only reason why I'd ever edit a text file in Pico or Nano, and not in Vim was its "Justify" command <kbd>^J</kbd>. It would reformat a paragraph of text, creating line breaks at word breaks so that the text would float on fixed width screen nicely - format the text to fit predefined 80 columns, creating line breaks only between words. As limited the function was, it was very useful, whether to format lengthy comment blocks, documentation files, or just replacing an endless line of parameters with something more readable.

Can I do something like that in Vim?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `gq` or `gw` operators combined with a motion command. By default, formatting of applicable text is done by Vim and to the best of my knowledge it does not justify the lines (you will get ragged right margins). Alternatively, an external program (e.g. the `fmt` command on Linux) can be used to do the formatting by specifying it with the `formatprg` setting.

The way I use it is to `gwip` (normal mode) with the cursor on a paragraph. This will format the current paragraph keeping the cursor on the same position. I use it this way to make sure that only the current paragraph is formatted. When editing a text file, issuing `gwG` (normal mode) at the begining of the file will format the whole text. As a good practice, be sure to leave at least one blank line between paragraphs.

There is a lot of configuration that can be done. To begin with, here are some relevant help: `:h gq`, `:h gw`, `:h fo` (format options), `:h fp` (format program), `:h fo-table` (an explanation of the possible options).

Comment: gq/gw is definitely the way to go. to add to this message you can change format program to par to have more options. Checkout http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/

Comment: By default, Vim doesn't use any external program, although you can choose to use one by setting the `'formatprg'` option.

Answer (score 19):

There is a great VimCast on this topic.

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/

Basically, you need to install `par`:

```
$ brew install par
# or
$ sudo apt-get install par
```

And then, since you want columns to be wrapped in 80 columns:

```
:set formatprg=par\ -w80
```

Now you can use the `gq` operator, like in other answers (e.g. `gqip`), and it will use Par instead of Vim's built-in formatter.

Par is quite advanced, and it will format comments like this nicely:

```
/* This is a long */
/* multiline comment */
```

Comment: In 2023 this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 18):

From `:help usr_25`:

```
JUSTIFYING TEXT                                                                 

Vim has no built-in way of justifying text.  However, there is a neat macro     
package that does the job.  To use this package, execute the following          
command:                                                                        

        :runtime macros/justify.vim                                             

This Vim script file defines a new visual command "_j".  To justify a block of  
text, highlight the text in Visual mode and then execute "_j".
```

So, all you have to do is run

```
:ru macros/justify.vim
```

and then type

```
_j
```

to justify the text in the entire file.

(Of course, you could also add `ru macros/justify.vim` to your .vimrc so you don't have to type it every time.)

**Note**: this does *not* add line breaks for you. You have to add those manually with `gq`. For this you must also set the `textwidth` (default is 0) to your desired value via

```
set textwidth=80
```

and—if you want—automatic text wrapping by setting the `t`-flag via

```
set formatoptions+=t
```

If you want, you can set a mapping in your .vimrc to do the entire thing for you:

```
nnoremap <C-j> gggqG_j
```

This moves to the beginning of the file (`gg`), wraps all the lines (`gq` until `G`), and then `_j`ustifies the text.

Comment: For a closer look on formatting, see: [VIM USER MANUAL - Editing formatted text](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_25.html)

Comment: I just found the very useful `:set fo+=a` option for automatic reformatting of the whole paragraph. Have a look at `:help fo-table` for other options. There also is a nice video tutorial [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/hard-wrapping-text/).

Comment: +1 for a completely built-in solution. The `_j` mapping added by the macro seems to justify the entire file for me, or it can be limited with a linewise visual selection.

Comment: One minor drawback I found is that `_j` tries stretching every selected line, including the last line of a paragraph (which normally should not be stretched). I would love that it would observe the convention adopted by `:set fo+=w` and only stretch lines which end with a space.

Answer (score 6):

While nano's help call the `^J` command "Justify" it actually doesn't [justify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Justified) the text, it reformat the text breaking the lines before the right margin of the screen (or at some configurable column, I guess).

You can do the same thing in VIM by setting the variable `textwidth`, from [`:help 'textwidth'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27):

> Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
>   broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
>   this.

That is to say: while you are typing, if a line is longer than `textwidth` characters, VIM will wrap the line at the first space to keep the line length less or equal to `textwidth`.

For this to work the option `formatoptions` must contain the letter `t`. See [`:help 'formatoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) and [`:help fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table) for the available options, for example you may be interested in the `c` option to make formatting work with comments.

**Edit**: you can perform the same operation, without the need to put `t` in `formatoptions`, using the command [`gw{motion}`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#gw), it formats the text between the current cursor position and the position of the cursor after `{motion}`. The [`gw`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_gw) command is available also in visual mode, it format the selected text.

Comment: That's good for typing. Can I apply that for pre-existing text?

Answer (score 5):

Here are two easy options:

1. with a block of text selected, type `!fmt`
2. with your cursor at the start of a block, type `!}fmt`

Both of these send a block of text to unix `fmt`, see `man fmt` for options. You can pass option arguments from vim. For example, to format a block a 50 characters wide, type `!}fmt -w 50`.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed now

Comment: You can also format your whole file by typing `:%!fmt` and undo with a single `u` if you don't like the result.

Comment: For me this is the only solution that worked. The above built in and macro solutions mess things up with the indent, and par is no-go if you do not have root access. `fmt` is typically installed because it comes with coreutils, and worked as intended.

Comment: Ah nevermind. For anyone reading, `gq` will also work as expected on a visual selection, as long as you `:set autoindent` and `:set textwidth` first.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the text using the visual command and then use:

```
:!par 40j
```

where 40 is the column width and `j` means justify.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Your question is of low quality currently because it lacks explanations about the tool you are using (`par`) and why your solution works. You might want to add more details to improve the quality of your answer and make it more useful for future readers.