# The indent of wrapped lines

Tags: wrapping, line-breaks

My vimrc about wrap is set like this:

```
set wrap "Wrap lines
set breakindent " indent after line wrapped
```

But the wrapped lines are not equal in length, such as:

```
line 1:   some contents ..... <end>
          continued line ..... other contents <end>
line 2: ....
```

The line 1 and its wrapped line does not agree in length, and neither of them is as long as the longest length the window provides.

Sometimes when I write Chinese characters, the line just wrapped at the position of space even though it is not finished, like this:

```
1.<space>
地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地
地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地寺地
```

or like this:

```
line 1: 地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地寺地
        地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地<space>
        地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地地
line 2: ...
```

How could I make the wrapped lines the same length, and thus make the paragraph a shape of rectangular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I justify text in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/509/can-i-justify-text-in-vim)

Comment: @HerbWolfe Sorry, I did not see explicit relation between that question and mine. Would you make it clearer?

Comment: What you are asking for is called full justification.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I know, and how about my second problem about Chinese characters or a combination of Chinese and English? The wrap points fall on the wrong places of where spaces are in stead of the Chinese word at the length of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Since [8.2.3198](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f674b358fc18cf1641a066cc5de73da69e651024) vim has `breadkindentopt` with `list:-1`:

```
'breakindentopt' 'briopt' string (default empty)
            local to window
            {not available when compiled without the |+linebreak|
            feature}
    Settings for 'breakindent'. It can consist of the following optional
    items and must be separated by a comma:

....

        list:{n}    Adds an additional indent for lines that match a
                numbered or bulleted list (using the
                'formatlistpat' setting).
        list:-1     Uses the length of a match with 'formatlistpat'
                for indentation.
```

Which you can use like:

```
set breakindent breakindentopt=sbr,list:-1 linebreak
" this should be set up per filetype probably
let &formatlistpat = '^line\s\+\d\+:\s*'
```

[image]

And without `linebreak` it looks more "rectangular"

```
set breakindent breakindentopt=sbr,list:-1
" this should be set up per filetype probably
let &formatlistpat = '^line\s\+\d\+:\s*'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, try `set formatoptions+=m`.

Also see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/7566at/how_to_use_set_wrap_for_chinese/) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! A little explanation via [edit] would go a long way, especially to avoid link-rot.